# How to combine columns when making a LaTeX table with pandas.DataFrame.to_latex?

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I have a DataFrame where I would like to format into a LaTeX table, with columns `df['FLUX']` and `df['FLUX_ERROR]` to be combined in the table such that the `df.to_latex()` will output these columns as flux+/-error i.e 100.0 $\pm$ .1.